# Weird error occurs when I combined JQuery's hide() function with Meteor's event

Tags: jquery, meteor

Hi I'm new to JQuery/Meteor, and currently encountered a weird issue and hopes if someone could help me.

I have created a click event in Meteor such that it allows user to click on a 'Delete' button in order to remove comments that were posted on the website from the database. Below is the code I have written for the click event.

```
"click .js-del-comment": function(event) {  

  Websites.update(this.databaseID, {$pull: {comments: {
                                            contentID: this.contentID
                                            }}});            
}
```

The code above works perfectly fine, but just whenever the user click on the "Delete" button, the comment disappears quickly. Thus, in order for the user to have a more pleasant view of the process, I have combined the above code with JQuery's `hide()` function, such that when the item/comment is being deleted, it will fade off slowly. The code below is my modified code combining with JQuery.

```
"click .js-del-comment": function(event){

        $("#" + this.contentID).hide('slow', function(){

            Websites.update(this.databaseID, {$pull: {comments: {
                                            contentID: this.contentID
                                            }}});
        });         
}
```

After combining my event code with JQuery, those comments/items were deleted from my website by slowly fading off, but however, whenever I refreshed my browser, those old deleted comments came back again. If I did not use the JQuery `hide()` function, the original code works fine and those deleted items/comments never came back even after I refreshed my browser.

Why is this weird issue happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context of `this` has changed.

Try binding the context of the callback:

```
$("#" + this.contentID).hide('slow', function(){
  Websites.update(this.databaseID, {
    $pull: {
      comments: {
          contentID: this.contentID
  }}});
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Or use an arrow function.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks a lot for your prompt response, but however i got another issue using bind. 
I have a delete button attached to every comment. Now after using bind, whenever i delete whichever comment, the sequential comment below it will be deleted as well, and only after i refreshed my browser then the sequential comment came back up. 
Example, if say i got 4 comments listed in sequence. If i delete comment 1, then comment 2 will be deleted automatically as well, and only after i refreshed my browser then comment 2 will re-surface.
Why is this happening?

Comment: I would assume they have conflicting `contentID`s. Hard to tell without some markup.

Comment: Hi Ivan, yeah I would think so as well. I will try to investigate my code along this path. Once again thanks.